# Python webscraping with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I wanna scrape stock tickers with beautifulsoup from this html site.
view-source:https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&pagesize=40

I wanna get the tickers from the H3 elements. Like "PIH"

```
<td>
  <h3>
     <a href="/symbol/pih">
     PIH</a>
  </h3>
</td>
```

So far i tried this:

```
    resp = requests.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&pagesize=40')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'genTable thin'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        ticker = row.findAll('h3')
        tickers.append(ticker)
```

The result i get is:

```
[[], [<h3>
<a href="/symbol/yi">
                                    YI</a>
</h3>], [], [<h3>
<a href="/symbol/pih">
                                    PIH</a>
</h3>], [], [<h3>
<a href="/symbol/pihpp">
                                    PIHPP</a>
</h3>], [], [<h3>
<a href="/symbol/turn">
                                    TURN</a>
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend using Scrapy, if you're actually going to build a serious scraper. https://scrapy.org/

Comment: Whats the advantage of scrapy.org to beautifulsoup?

Comment: Scrapy is a framework fundamentally built for web scraping, you can integrate easy selectors, and parse complex Javascript rendered web pages using Phantom JS. It's pretty incredible to say the least, My day job requires me to write multiple scrapers a day and trust me I wouldn't know what to do if it wasn't for scrapy. Side note - you haven't accepted any answers as the "correct one" could you please select that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

resp = requests.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&pagesize=40')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'genTable thin'})
tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    for ticker in row.findAll('h3'):
        tickers.append(ticker.text.strip()) # extract the text from the element and strip out extra spaces, escape sequences. 
print(tickers)
```

Output:

```
['YI', 'PIH', 'PIHPP', 'TURN', 'FLWS', 'BCOW', 'FCCY', 'SRCE', 'VNET', 'TWOU', 'QFIN', 'JOBS', 'JFK', 'JFKKR', 'JFKKU', 'JFKKW', 'EGHT', 'JFU', 'AAON', 'ABEO', 'ABEOW', 'ABIL', 'ABMD', 'AXAS', 'ACIU', 'ACIA', 'ACTG', 'ACHC', 'ACAD', 'ACAM', 'ACAMU', 'ACAMW', 'ACST', 'AXDX', 'XLRN', 'ARAY', 'ACRX', 'ACER', 'ACHV', 'ACHN']
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/RedStaticQuarks).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the text like this

```
resp = requests.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&pagesize=40')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'genTable thin'})
tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    ticker = row.findAll('h3')
    if ticker == []:
        pass
    else:
        print(ticker[0].text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using CSS selector and list-comprehension:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&pagesize=40')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

tickers = [h3.get_text(strip=True) for h3 in soup.select('#CompanylistResults h3')]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(tickers)
```

Prints:

```
['YI',
 'PIH',
 'PIHPP',
 'TURN',
 'FLWS',
 'BCOW',
 'FCCY',
 'SRCE',
 'VNET',

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` to find the ticker links and extract the text:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&pagesize=40').text, 'html.parser')
r = [*{i['href'].split('/')[-1].upper() for i in d.find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('/symbol/\w+$')})}]
```

Output:

```
['PIH', 'JFK', 'FCCY', 'AXAS', 'FLWS', 'ACHC', 'ACIA', 'AXDX', 'JFKKW', 'ACAM', 'ACST', 'XLRN', 'ACTG', 'JFU', 'ABEOW', 'ABIL', 'ACER', 'ACIU', 'YI', 'ABEO', 'ACAMW', 'ACRX', 'ACHN', 'JOBS', 'ARAY', 'PIHPP', 'TWOU', 'ACAMU', 'ACHV', 'AAON', 'QFIN', 'SRCE', 'VNET', 'BCOW', 'JFKKR', 'ACAD', 'TURN', 'EGHT', 'JFKKU', 'ABMD']
```

To filter tickers with non alphanumeric characters, you can use `re`:

```
results = [i for i in r if re.findall('^[A-Z]+$', i)]
```

Comment: How can i filter symbols that look like this: 'PLYM^A', 'NRCG.WS', 'GLV~' ?    I dont want symbols added to the list when they contain the chars '^' or '.' or '~'